# "Next tag badge" progress bar does not update

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, user-accounts

When you are on the "Activity" tab of your user profile you can choose to track the progress towards tag badges. This however does not update when you get new rep/answer more questions, unless you un-select and re-select to track that tag badge.

For example tracking the "public-transport" badge on my site on the upper left it currently shows "70/100 score" and "5/20 answers" whereas the "tags" field (lower right) reveals that I have 88 score from 8 posts. When I select another badge this updates to the correct scores.

[image]

Comment: Counts for badges are timed by a cron-job. This might be why the update isn't instantaneous.

Comment: @JoErNanO the count in the lower right updates every night, the bar on the upper left however did not update for weeks, that is the bug I am filing.

Comment: As of recently this bug seems to have been resolved, both under tags and in the progress bar the count updates almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer, to copy a Comment from @mts:

> As of recently this bug seems to have been resolved, both under tags and in the progress bar the count updates almost instantly. – mts Jul 10 at 14:49